# How to populate AudioStreamBasicDescription for AMR_WB playback?

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, amr

I have an android device sending me audio in AMR_WB format with 16_000 sample rate and channel is mono.

```
var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
asbd.mSampleRate = Float64(sampleRate) // value: 16_000
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatAMR_WB
asbd.mFormatFlags = 0
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = UInt32(channels) // value: 1
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * UInt32(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
asbd.mReserved = 0
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = asbd.mChannelsPerFrame * UInt32(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = asbd.mBytesPerFrame * asbd.mFramesPerPacket
let _audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &asbd)!
return _audioFormat
```

When I am sending this to the `AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer`, but I am getting the following error

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (1885696621), 
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x283fb1920 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1885696621 "(null)" 
UserInfo={AVErrorFourCharCode='perm'}}}
```

Some old questions say that AMR is not supported on iOS, but I am able to find the codec ID in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiotypes/coreaudiotype_constants/1572096-audio_data_format_identifiers)

Comment: Apple pulled the AMR codec in iOS 4.3 for reasons.

Comment: sure, but in the current developer documentation, I see that [kAudioFormatAMR_WB](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiotypes/kaudioformatamr_wb) is supported from iOS 8+. Which led me to believe it's supported, no proper documentation of supported formats leads to effort being wasted.

Comment: That is strange, maybe the 8.0+ means the symbol is supported, not the codec? Anyway, as the doco says "No overview available." Welcome to Apple media APIs.